# Is a default export actually a named export in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I have read now for a number of times that a default export is actually just a named export with the name `default`. Now this makes me wonder what the behavior is when mixing default and named exports: Usually, they play nicely together. But what if I define a default export, and a named export named `default`?

What is the intended behavior of the runtime / compiler here?

Comment: `deafult` is a keyword you can't use as variable name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> a named export named default

This is not possible, because `default` is a reserved keyword. If you try to do something like

```
export const default = 'bar';
```

or try to name a variable `default` and then export it

```
const default = 'bar';
export default;
```

the interpreter will throw a SyntaxError and refuse to continue parsing.

So, no such collisions are possible.

Comment: Makes perfectly sense, thanks a lot! As soon as I can accept an answer, I will do so!

Answer (score 2):

Any reserved keyword can not be used as variable name ( identifier ),[`default`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/default) is a keyword so you can't use it as variable name, interpreter will trow error

[`Identifier expected`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Reserved_identifier)

The error statement depends on browser

```
SyntaxError: The use of a future reserved word for an identifier is invalid (Edge)
SyntaxError: "x" is a reserved identifier (Firefox)
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word (Chrome)
```

when you try this

```
export const default = {some: value}
```

[image]